# Initialize object in other class

Tags: ios, objective-c

i want to ask this question to clarify my knowledge.

I have an XML file, which have elements like - name, description, latitude, longitude etc. I decide to make custom class PlaceHolder, with properties like : @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name; @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *description; and other.

What i want is, to add object of that class to other. How should i init this right? And may i add it like a property to other class?

At now, in any function i need to use that class i do following:

```
PlaceHolder *place = [[PlaceHolder alloc]init];
place.name = @"";
place.description = @"";
```

Its not very convenient to init this every time, is there any way to add PlaceHolder class like property to other class?

Comment: Why not just create a "factory" method `newPlaceHolderWithName: andDescription:`?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you are asking. yes, you can add a PlaceHolder property to a class. Then, you can add code that creates a PlaceHolder object where appropriate.

If the class you're creating always needs a PlaceHolder object then you can write a custom init method that creates one and installs it in the property.

If it's a view controller and only needs a PlaceHolder when the view is displayed, you could add code to your viewDidLoad that creates a PlaceHolder and installs it in the property.

A third approach would be to write a custom getter for your property and "lazy load" the PlaceHolder object the first time you reference it.

You need to provide more information if you want better guidance than that.